# Laravel Eloquent: Query table, Fetch X number of rows on specific day (and allow for Pagination)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Imagine we have a table `tasks_complete`. It has thousands of rows with data over the past two years.

In that table is a column called `task_complete_date`.

We want to fetch `25` from each date and then apply pagination.

So what we should end up with is a full list of dates, but only `25` rows from each date and the standard pagination output.

I've looked at Subqueries and **left joins**, but sadly can't get this to work.

Basic example code is fine I can go from there

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve isn't possible with only one eloquent query and default pagination.

Checkout below code to start with:

```
$taskCompleteDates = TaskComplete::groupBy('task_complete_date')->pluck('task_complete_date');
$taskDates = array();
foreach($taskCompleteDates as $date)
{
    $tasks = TaskComplete::where('task_complete_date','=',$date)->limit(25)->get();
    $taskDates[$date] = $tasks;
}
```

Here first we are getting Distinct dates from table then for each date we are getting 25 tasks. and merging all data in **taskDates** array.

Now you will need to implement custom pagination code.

For custom pagination, You can refer below link:

[Pagination on collection](https://gist.github.com/iamsajidjaved/4bd59517e4364ecec98436debdc51ecc)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following maybe:

```
$collection = new Collection();
$dates = TasksComplete::select('task_complete_date')->groupBy('task_complete_date')->get();
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $limited = TasksComplete::where('task_complete_date', $date)->take(25)->get();
    foreach ($limited as $limit) {
        $collection->push($limit);
    }
}

And then create custom pagination
```